# R - fill blank values based on id

Tags: r, dplyr

Small question: I would like to fill the value of `id2` based on the grouping of `id`.

From this

```
> head(dta)
    id     id2
1 B10388W4       0
2 B10388W4 B10388W
3 B10388W4 B10388W
```

to simply that

```
    id     id2
1 B10388W4 B10388W
2 B10388W4 B10388W
3 B10388W4 B10388W
```

What would be a neat way fill values based on the group `id` ?

I thought of something like

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate( id3 = ifelse(id2 == 0, lead(id2), id2) )
```

But it's not so smart because some 0 could be found elsewhere for the same `id`.

Any ideas welcome.

The data

```
dta = structure(list(id = c("B10388W4", "B10388W4", "B10388W4"), 
id2 = c("0", "B10388W", "B10388W")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "id2"))
```

Comment: You could convert zeros to `NA`s and then use `zoo::na.locf` or you could fill with `unique(id2[id2 != 0])` instead of `lead(id2)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For each `id` (group) you can use the unique `id2` value which is not `0`, and update you `id2` column. This assumes that for each unique `id` value there is only one unique `id2` value and maybe a `0` value as well.

```
# my example dataset
dt = data.frame(id = c("B10388W4","B10388W4","B10388W4","A10388W4","A10388W4","A10388W4"),
                id2 = c(0,"B10388W","B10388W","A10388W",0,0),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

dt

#         id     id2
# 1 B10388W4       0
# 2 B10388W4 B10388W
# 3 B10388W4 B10388W
# 4 A10388W4 A10388W
# 5 A10388W4       0
# 6 A10388W4       0


library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(id2_new = unique(id2[id2 != 0])) %>%
select(-id2) %>%
ungroup

#          id id2_new
#       (chr)   (chr)
# 1 A10388W4 A10388W
# 2 A10388W4 A10388W
# 3 A10388W4 A10388W
# 4 B10388W4 B10388W
# 5 B10388W4 B10388W
# 6 B10388W4 B10388W
```

Comment: Any reason to prefer `do` over `mutate`?  Seems like `mutate(id2_new = unique(id2[id2 != 0]))` would achieve the desired results.

Comment: `do` over-complicates things. I have no idea why I didn't use the obvious `mutate` here. Will update. Thanks for the comment @aosmith .

Answer (score 0):

```
dta %>%
  filter(id2 != 0) %>%
  distinct %>%
  full_join(dta %>% select(id1) )
```